# Google Analytics API, filter by parameter

Tags: google-analytics-api

Our app uses the Google Analytics Rest API. We'd like to get the number of page views generated by different links to the site.

For example, one link to our site might be:

```
http://oursite.com?linknum=12345
```

and another might be:

```
http://oursite.com?linknum=23456
```

We'd like to track the number of page views by all visitors who click on each link, so we need a way to filter by parameter.

So far, we just get the number of page views for all visitors without any filters:

```
curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:(our id) &metrics=ga:pageviews&start-date=2014-4-26&end-date=2011-12-08&access_token=(our access token)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to learn the API is to use the query explorer at
http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

For your analysis, add dimension=ga:pagePath and sort=ga:pageviews.

In addition, you could ask for pages which match a filter expression. 
For example filter=ga:pagePath=@linknum to only include pages with linknum.